# ChannelGroup send handler level

Tags: performance, broadcast

ChannelGroup send handler level?

I am Simon from China,We have project base on Netty.
We have 3 handler in the ChannelPipeline for send Object Message to the Clients.

1 BusinessHandler - 2 ActionEncoder - 3 FrameEncoder

1 BusinessHandler for business logic like save to database.

2 ActionEncoder for encoder Object to ByteBuf.

3 FrameEncoder for frame Head and Foot.

That all.

When we send a Object Message with ChannelGroup to All Clients 
that Netty need process each client channel for each handler (1-2-3) just like:

```
for(channel:Channels){
    for(handler:Handlers){
        data;
    }
    send;
}
```

I think this slowly process,I wish the ChannelGroup send like this:
first process all handler make Object Message to the ByteBuf,
next send to all clients with ChannelGroup.

```
for(handler:Handlers){
    data;
}
for(channel:Channels){
    send;
}
```

Please tell me know haw todo this?